# jQuery-styled checkboxes lose their style when they are ajax-updated

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using p:commandButton to show a dialog, here is my code:

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="actions">
  <h:form>
    <p:commandButton value="Select" styleClass="select"
      action="#{antecedants.initFA('hyper',1)}"
      update=":dialog" oncomplete="select_hyper.show()"/>
  </h:form> 
</h:panelGroup>
```

The dialog contains h:selectManyCheckbox, I customized the checkbox icon using css.
The problem is when I open the dialog, it opens with the default checkbox icon not the customized one, when i remove update=":dialog" from commandButton it works fine, I see the checkbox with my customized icon.
I need to keep the update. Any help please?

Comment: are you sure there is only css customizing the checkbox icon? it seems there is some javascript code doing that, and it is not placed in the dialog, so it doesn't run after the update operation.

Comment: Why don't you try to wrap what you have into the dialog and update the wrapper instead of the dialog itself?

Comment: @tt_emrah yes your are right there is some javascript code doing that

Comment: The javascript code is called from another xhtml page that I am using as template. How can I call it again in update?

Comment: wrap that js code in another `h:panelGroup`, give that panelGroup an id, and update it together with `:dialog`, after the `:dialog`. i guess... :)

Comment: Resolved, in fact JQUERY is used to manage chckbox behavior. so I used '<p:ajaxStatus oncomplete="selectionBehavior()" />' to recall selectionBehavior() JQUERY function after update

Comment: but that will execute `selectionBehavior()` after each and every ajax request. do you really want that? client cpu time is precious.

Comment: Oups you are right (again) I am having performance issues now, so i remove it.

Comment: Here is how i did and it's working: in the p:commandButton that opens the dialog I added on complete a call to the style_checkboxes() JQuery function that puts the correct style.                  '<p:commandButton value="Select" styleClass="select"
action="#{ant('mr',1)}" update=":dialog21" oncomplete="select_maladiesRenales.show();style_checkboxes();"/>'     Thanks guys for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how i did and it's working: in the p:commandButton that opens the dialog I added on complete a call to the style_checkboxes() JQuery function that puts the correct style.

```
<p:commandButton value="Select" styleClass="select" action="#{ant('mr',1)}"update=":dialog21"oncomplete="select_maladiesRenales.show();style_checkboxes();"/>
```

Thanks guys for help.

Comment: i don't know why i missed doing it in `oncomplete`. you are correct.

Comment: @yassine you can accept your own answer by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution.